# Can an sobject be queried using One of the Sobject Field's lookup filter criteria in Apex

Tags: apex, lookup, lookup-filter

Is there any Apex API like to get the Lookup filter condition defined on an sObjectField of type "lookup" so that the condition can be used in SOQL.

Comment: The metadata API will allow you to do this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zhKIAQ - I do not see a method in the `describefieldresult` class but I could have missed it. documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/namedfilter.htm

Comment: @Eric Thanks for references.
I started going through Metadata API documentation, seems like its not small as I assumed. Thanks again.